# Could not find a part of the path in File.ReadAllText, but the path exists

Tags: c#, web-services, path

I have a webservice that reference a library.
This library project (C# fw v4.5) reads files like templates.
In my code i have this:

```
File.ReadAllText(applicationDir + @"EmailTemplates\Contact.cshtml")
```

I'm getting `applicationDir` like this:

```
string applicationDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath) + "\\";
```

This is throwing the `Could not find a part of the path` exception but the path exists on my disc. Why this is happening? i have checked the path, the permissions and i dont have any idea why is this happening.
The only thing that may be is that in the path there is a space.
This is the path: `C:\Work\Main\Source\Mailing System\Source\MailBLL\EmailTemplates\Contact.cshtml` and in the code (debuging) i see it like this:

```
C:\\Work\\Main\\Source\\Mailing%20System\\Source\\MailBLL\\EmailTemplates\\Contact.cshtml
```

**Edit/First solution**:

I just figured out that the problem is the `%20` on the path! i have added a replace in the `applicationDir` and works perfect! but i dont found this as a permanent solution, is there a way that the code does not put that `%20` and instead put the space?

Comment: Have you tried `File.Exists(YourPath)` ? What does it return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the space between the folder name "Mailing System" is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem but i need a more nice solution that a simple Replace... or it isnt?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath) 
                              ,@"EmailTemplates\Contact.cshtml"));
```

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, try `File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath) 
                              ,@"EmailTemplates\Contact.cshtml"));`

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, store that path in a string variable and post here what you see in the debugger

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase is deprecated in dotnet core v5

Answer (score 1):

Your `File.Exists(YourPath)` return false.
 From MSDN, here is what they say about it :

`true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.`

Do you have permissions to access this file ?
The way you're getting your path might be the problem. Could you try this and see if it works :

```
File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Work\Main\Source\Mailing System\Source\MailBLL\EmailTemplates\Contact.cshtml");
```