# Invalid Characters in FileName

Tags: c#, file-io

I fail to see what's invalid about this one (this is an example of a similar string I have in my code) that the runtime complains about saying I have invalid characters in my filepath whenI try do perform a File.ReadAllText on that file.

```
var somePath = @"C:\www\SomeDirectory1\SomeDirectory1 1.2\SomeDirectory1.Applications\InventoryGetRequest.txt";
```

More info

So I think the error is actually here:

it's trying to append the following string to the file:

```
        private const string textToStore= @"{
                                        ""ErrorMessage"": """",
                                        ""ErrorDetails"": {
                                                        ""ErrorID"": 111,
                                                        ""Description"": {
                                                                            ""Short"": 0,
                                                                            ""Verbose"": 20
                                                                        },

                                   ""ErrorDate"": """"
                                        }
                                }";

.....
            using (var fs = new FileStream(txtFilePath, FileMode.Truncate))
            {
                File.AppendText(textToStore);
            }
```

If I just change textToStore = "test" it doesn't bomb out so is it my json string?

Comment: How exactly does “the runtime complains about” it? It throws an exception? Post the exception.

Comment: could it be the space in "SomeDirectory1 1.2"?

Comment: Even with the `@`, you may need to escape the space when it is being passed to the method.

Comment: It certainly may be the space. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328008/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-in-file-readalltext-but-the-path-exists

Comment: *"this is an example of a similar string I have in my code"* meaning *"I didn't really give you the actual problematic string, please debug using psychic powers"*?

Comment: so it looks like maybe the path is ok, but the string I'm trying to append to that txt file is not making this happy

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - are you saying this question is invalid?

Comment: see updates, I added more

Comment: @Eric, the sample string is good enough, it's exactly the same format I have...so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when you ask the community to debug for you, without sharing either code or the exception, it's rather critical that the one bit of data you do provide is actually a part of the problem. It's not safe to assume that it's "exactly the same format" unless it's "exactly the same".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrectly using [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it returns a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you're expected to feed with some content :

```
using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText("hello.txt"))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine("example");
}
```

Or as @Selman22 suggested, if you prefer a one-liner use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead :

```
File.AppendAllText("hello.txt", "example");
```

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for `File.AppendAllText` method. @CoffeeAddict

Comment: awesome the 2nd is much more elegant and worked.  Now I just gotta figure out how to clear the file first of previous content.  Anyway thanks

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong, but I think javascript uses forward slashes for directories, not backslashes. I believe backslashes are only used for escape sequences. Try replacing them and post back and let us know if this works. Good luck!

EDIT: I did not realize at first this was C#. Try replacing the single backslashes with double backslashes.

Comment: This is c#, not javascript

Comment: Woops, I saw the "var" and missed the fact this was c#. My apologies =P

Comment: There used verbatim string.

Comment: @derstrom8 The edit wont work because he used a verbatim string. Notice the '@'.

Comment: I think I'd better leave this thread, I have been missing all sorts of things today =P Thanks for your patience.

Comment: right I'm working with C#...to store json strings to a txt